# Need to find the downtime for DNS migration from Godaddy to Route53

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-zone, amazon-route53, godaddy

I have the domain registered in Godaddy. I also have a lot of subdomains and other values in my Godaddy DNS management console. But now, I need to point my domain to an application that is under AWS Cloudfront. I'm planning to migrate DNS services from Godaddy to AWS Route53.

I have created a hosted zone for my domain name and transferred all my values in Godaddy by importing the zone file in Route53.

I'm planning to change the Godaddy Nameservers with AWS Route53's Nameservers. But I want to know if there are any unexpected downtime. Or normally how much time will it take for this change to get affected. I have more than 30 values in my Godaddy DNS management console.

Is there any unpredicted downtime?

Comment: dns server takes days depending on your ttl settings,, imho its better to reduce the ttl wait 3 days after this transfer should be ij nearly instantly successfully

Comment: You can expect downtime - but this will likely due to your lack of understanding of the DNS system. Get an expert to walk you through it, as it is easy to do without downtime, or with no more then a few minutes downtime depending on your exact needs.  If you have a proper migration plan it might be a more appropriate question.

Comment: The maximum value that can be seen in the Godaddy DNS management page is 1 Hour. That is for type MX, NS, SOA and TXT. So, if we change the Nameservers, the maximum downtime will be 1 hour. Is that so? Is my understanding wrong?

Comment: As @djdomi said, if I change all the TTL values to a smaller values first, say 600 seconds for example. Then I waited for 1 or 2 hours for this change to take place. After that I change the Nameservers, it will take only less downtime. Am I wrong?

Comment: thats correctly @neronjoseph howevrr there is no downtime in fact in case on both running the same data

Comment: Is there any proper answer to the question? I'm too in the place of @neronjoseph. In godaddy the TTL for NS records are 1Hour and I'm unable to edit those. How can we do the transfer without downtime?